# Getting data from posts in each page using php

Tags: php, dom, curl, php-5.6

This is for getting title and date from each posts (from forbes.com) using curl and PHP Dom. When I print date inside foreach, title and time is showing correct count "30". But My problem is when I print insert query, result getting is wrong. Each page has 15 posts below code is for getting data from two pages. please check below code and help me to solve this issue?

```
<?php
require_once('dbconnect.php');

//use curl to get html content
function getHTML($url)
{
    $curl=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/cookies.txt');
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}

$url                                 = "http://www.forbes.com/search/post/REIT/15/All-time/0/";
$results                             = getHTML($url);
$dom_document                        = new DOMDocument();
$dom_document->loadHTML($results);
$remove[]                            = ",";
$remove[]                            = " ";
$remove[]                            = "results";

/* ############################################################################ Total ###################################################################*/
$total_results                       = @$dom_document->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($total_results as $total_result) {
    $total_result_class = $total_result->getAttribute('class');
    if(strstr($total_result_class, 'total_records')){
        $total_result_replace = str_replace($remove, '', $total_result->textContent);
    }
}
$pages_divide = $total_result_replace / 15;          //338.4666
$pages_floor  = floor($pages_divide);               //338

for($i = 1; $i<= 2; $i++) { // $i<= 2 (two page)
    $url_without_page       = "http://www.forbes.com/search/post/REIT/15/All-time/";
    $url_with_page          = $url_without_page . $i . '/';
    /*echo '<pre>';
      print_r($url_with_page);*/
    $url_pages              = getHTML($url_with_page);
    $dom_document_pages     = new DOMDocument();
    $dom_document_pages->loadHTML($url_pages);

    /* ############################################################################ Title ###################################################################*/
    $title_result                             = array();
    $titles                                   = @$dom_document_pages->getElementsByTagName('h2');
    foreach ($titles as $title) {
        foreach($title->childNodes as $nodes){
            if($nodes->tagName == 'a'){
                $title_result                 = str_replace("'", "", $nodes->textContent);
                /* echo '<pre>';
                   print_r($title_result);*/  
            }
        }

    }

    /* ############################################################################# Time ###################################################################*/
    $time_result                  = array();
    $times                        = @$dom_document_pages->getElementsByTagName('time');
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        $date                     = new DateTime();
        $date_replace             = str_replace(",", "", $time->textContent); //Feb 10, 2016
        $string_to_time           = strtotime($date_replace);
        $date->setTimestamp($string_to_time);
        $time_result             = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        /*echo '<pre>';
          print_r($time_result);*/
    }
    $query_insert                  = "INSERT INTO article_forbes(title, datetime) VALUE ('".$title_result."', '".$time_result."')";
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $query_insert;
    //$mysqli->query($query_insert);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean the time is showing correctly `"30"`? That's not a time.

Comment: Why are you doing loops to get the titles and times, and then only inserting the last of each? And what's the point of setting `$title_result` to an array, then in the loop you set it to a single title. You do the same thing with `$time_result`.

Comment: @Barmar "30" means count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not inserting the data inside the loops. So you're just inserting the last title and the last time.

You initialized `$title_result` and `$time_result` to arrays, so I suspect you originally intended to collect all the titles and times there. But then instead of pushing them onto the arrays in the loops, you replaced the arrays with strings. Change

```
$title_result = str_replace("'", "", $nodes->textContent);
```

to

```
$title_result[] = $nodes->textContent;
```

so that you push onto the array, and make a similar change to `$time_result`.

Then you should do the inserts in a loop.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare("INSERT INTO article_forbes(title, datetime) VALUES (?, ?)");
mysqli_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $title, $time);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($title_result); $i++) {
    $title = $title_result[$i];
    $time = $time_result[$i];
    mysqli_execute($stmt);
}
```

Using a prepared statement like this means you don't need to remove special characters from the title.

Comment: Currently I am getting only 15 entries But I have written code for 30 entries.

Comment: I don't see a reason. It should get 15 entries on each page.

Comment: I am sorry. I added for-loop inside another for-loop. Now everything is clear and correct. Thanks for your support.